Auto generate browse/form pair given a database object?
In Visual Studio, it is possible to create a data source, then drag and drop a database object onto a form and automatically have a bound DataGridView generated. This is very close to what I seek, but I wish to modify/extend the manner in which the generation is performed. I am unable locate any information that provides the location of the template (?) file that performs the auto-generation.
An alternative would be to find a 3rd-party product that auto-generates a classic browse/form pair given a database object. In this situation, a browse would be the listing of records. A DataGridView with three buttons (Insert, Change, Delete) would suffice. When the Insert or Change buttons are pressed, a form window would appear allowing the modification of the record.
I want this to be auto-generated as I have many database tables that would need have browse/form window pairs to be generated.
Question 1: Is it possible to access and modify the Visual Studio template that does the generation when a database object is dragged and dropped onto a form? I cannot find any information in Google searches.
Question 2: Does there exist a 3rd-party product that would do this?

Question 1: Unfortunately, Visual Studio's built-in data binding and auto-generation features are not easily customizable through templates or exposed for modification. While Visual Studio provides wizards and designers for generating data-bound controls like DataGridViews, there isn't a straightforward way to modify the underlying templates or behavior.
Question 2:  You could try to get third-party tools through Google Third UI WinForms or Third WinForms Controls.
Before selecting a third-party tool, evaluate its features, compatibility with your development environment, and licensing terms to ensure it meets your requirements. Additionally, consider the long-term maintenance and support implications of using a third-party solution in your project.
